# Dynamic Table Query

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following list of `Tuples` that I'm filling with a header/column name followed by a list of values that could be found in that column. I then want to query a `DataTable` with the whole list.

```
List<Tuple<string, IEnumerable<string>>> filters = new List<Tuple<string, IEnumerable<string>>>();
```

Now I'm doing the below, running each as a separate query, filtering one by one in a loop. But I believe there should be a way to do this without having to loop and run multiple queries. I.e. apply all the queries together, at once.

```
var dataTemp = MyDataTable.AsEnumerable();
foreach (var filter in filters)
{
datTemp = datTemp.Where(row => filter.Item2.Contains(row.Field<String>(filter.Item1)));
}
return dataTemp;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to test each row against all the filters:

```
var dataTemp = MyDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                   .Where(row => filters.All(filter => filter.Item2.Contains(row.Field<string>(filter.Item1))));
```

Depending on the nature of your filter `IEnumerable<string>`, you may want to convert the filters for faster processing:

```
var fastFilters = filters.Select(f => (f.Item1, new HashSet<string>(f.Item2)));

var dataTemp = MyDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                   .Where(row => fastFilters.All(filter => filter.Item2.Contains(row.Field<string>(filter.Item1))));
```

I normally use an extension for converting an `IEnumerable<>` to a `HashSet`:

```
public static HashSet<T> ToHashSet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) => new HashSet<T>(source);
```

Then you can have

```
var fastFilters = filters.Select(f => (f.Item1, f.Item2.ToHashSet()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the linq query:

```
filters.Aggregate(dataTemp, 
            (current, filter) => current.Where(row => filter.Item2.Contains(row.Field<string>(filter.Item1))));
```

You can also possibly implement an extension method:

```
    public static EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> CustomFilter(this DataTable @this,
        IEnumerable<Tuple<string, IEnumerable<string>>> filters)
    {
        var dataTemp = @this.AsEnumerable();
        return filters.Aggregate(dataTemp, 
            (current, filter) => current.Where(row => filter.Item2.Contains(row.Field<string>(filter.Item1))));
    }
```